# Typo3 CMS keeps kicking me out

Tags: azure-web-app-service, typo3, azure-cloud-services

We have moved our website which uses typo3 from on-prem to Azure cloud. We setup a Front door with firewall protection which is different from the previous setup.

Since day one when I log in I can do some stuff for a short while (like 4-5 minutes) and then it kicks me out to login screen.

Another example is when I'm logged in, I open a new tab and check some other sites then go back to typo3, again I'm logged out. Need to log in again.

I lost some of my posts while adding some additional info from other websites.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check, just after login, how many "be_typo_user" cookies there are?

Comment: AFAIK the backend checks the `Referrer` header to be present. I would check if the Firewall is not tampering with that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I resolved it with replacing `lockIP` in the install tool from 4 to 0.

Note, this is a temp solution so you can keep working, but you really need to find out why this is happening.

Best regards